# Pandas: convert WinZipped csv file to Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a couple of WinZipped csv files and would like to read these in as a Pandas dataframe. The problem is that neither of the decompression options ('gzip' or 'bz2') seems to work. Here's what the file looks like:

```
00000000011!00023011!89011!200812
00000000012!00023011!89011!200812
00000000013!00023011!89011!200812
```

So it seems that I am going to have to unzip the file using Python's zipfile module, read in the lines and create a dataframe from what I read in. The way I thought about doing this is creating a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[
    {"header1": 00000000011, "header2": 00023011, "header3": 89011, "header4": 200812}, 
    {"header1": 00000000012, "header2": 00023011, "header3": 89011, "header4": 200812},
    ...
]
```

and then convert this to a dataframe as in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#from-a-list-of-dicts.

However, this seems to involve a lot of manual manipulating of lines - is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to unzip the file:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/file', 'r') as z:
    f = z.open('member.csv')
    table = pd.io.parsers.read_table(f, ...)
```

The `filepath_or_buffer` parameter to `read_table` accepts any file-like argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been trying to see if that works, the problem is that the archive in `zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/file', 'r')` contains several files. Any idea how I provide the path to one of the files in the archive?

Comment: FWIW I needed to do : zipfile.Zipfile ('path/to/file'. 'r')as z: instead of the specified 1st line of the solution

Answer (score 3):

**Pandas 0.18.1** added Zip support out of the box:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_zipped_csv.zip', compression = 'zip')
```

In fact, since the default param is `compression = 'infer'`, you can just throw anything with a `.zip` extension at it, and it'll know what to do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_zipped_csv.zip')
```