# Take a subset of dataframe as TextParser object

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a csv files in chunks using pandas, but would only like to take a subset of the columns. I am trying to use

```
df = pandas.io.parsers.read_table(myData, chunksize=1000)
df = df[id_fields + [time_field] + value_fields]
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
TextFileReader' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The same code works if I drop the chunksize bit:

```
df = pandas.io.parsers.read_table(myData)
df = df[id_fields + [time_field] + value_fields]
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk, when passed chunksize an ``iterator`` is reeturned not a frame, you need to iterator to get the chunk. also you  should use ``pd.read_table``

Comment: @Jeff - what's the difference between pandas.read_table and pandas.io.parsers.read_table? The only reason I was using the latter was because it was suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17789907/2565842...

Comment: same (but starting in 0.12 all *public* methods like this will be exported in the top-level name space (so you dont' have to know where to find them), e.g. ``pd.read_excel`` is actually in a different module, but you won't care ``pd.read_table`` is already in the top-level namespace  in 0.11 (and before for a while)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the smartest solution (e.g. if most chunks are useless to you), but the following should do what you want:

```
it = pandas.read_table(myData, chunksize=1000)
df = pandas.concat([chunk[id_fields + [time_field] + value_fields]
                    for chunk in it])
```